# Fetching all rows with SELECT *

Tags: cassandra

I have one million rows in my cassandra keyspace.
I want to fetch all my rows with `select * from my_keyspace`, but I only get about 200 rows. How I can increase this number? **LIMIT 1000000** doesnt work.

Comment: How do you know there are 1 Million rows? Sounds like you may have overwritten rows you already had in the DB.

Comment: I have imported them from csv-file, so I know the exact number of the rows.
1000209 rows imported from 1 files in 16.523 seconds (0 skipped).

Now I want Cassandra to show them to me. I want to show how long does it take to make that request (with tracing). But as I say, select * gives me only about 200 rows...

Comment: If it only gives you 200 rows it means your overwrote your previous rows ie 
If you insert (1, 1) (1, 2), (1, 3) into a table (K, V, Primary Key (K)) you get 1 row

Comment: Can you please explain?
I have:
`create table movies_1m (movie_id int, title text, user_id int, rating decimal, primary key (movie_id, user_id)) ;

copy movies_1m (movie_id, title, rating, user_id) from 'cassandra_1m.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ';';`

Comment: Your schema says there can only be 1 Row per unique combination of movie_id and user_id.

Comment: Yes, it's right. All rows are unique.  And I also have something like:
     1580 |    5333 |    4.0 | Men in Black (1997)
     1580 |    5336 |    3.0 | Men in Black (1997)
     1580 |    5337 |    5.0 | Men in Black (1997)
in my 200 rows.

Comment: run Select Count(*)

Comment: count
---------
 1000209

(1 rows)

Comment: Then i'm at a loss, there is no reason for it to only return 200 rows.